# Circular image is square on first table refresh

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a search bar connected to my `UITableView`.

Here is my code so far:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = SongPicker.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!

    // Image
    cell.imageView?.image = songHandler.songItems[indexPath.row].songImage?.cropToBounds()
    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView!.frame.width / 2
    cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 3
    cell.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

    // Song name
    cell.textLabel?.text = songHandler.songItems[indexPath.row].songName

    // Artist name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = songHandler.songItems[indexPath.row].songArtist

    return cell
}
```

(`SongPicker` is my table)

By printing out the result of `cell.imageView?.layer`, I can see that when the images first load, they do not have the `cornerRadius` property set within the instance. After they reload properly, the property is set.

However, when the cells move out of view or updated via getting new information (`.reloadData()` does nothing), the images in the cells are circular.

There are other question about this, but everyone repeats that you need to set the `cornerRadius` property and the `masksToBounds`. This, in no way, would help solve my problem as those properties are clearly set.

I have tried making an extension to a `UITableViewCell` with the image layer code as well, but it has the exact same results.

Why are my images starting off square, and how can I easily fix this?

[image]

**If you have any question please ask**

Comment: Did you try setting your `cornerRadius` in the Storyboard (setting `layer.cornerRadius` of type `Number` in the **User Dedined Runtime Attributes**)? Also, don't use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` as it could return `nil` and crash your app due to the forced unwrapping. Use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:, for:)` which ensures an actual `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the `imageView's frame` is `.zero` at the moment when you are setting the `cornerRadius` of its layer. If you have fix size for the `imageView` then you can set `cornerRadius` as half of the `width` and it will work fine. Something as below,

```
cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 50 //If width&height is 100 fix.
```

Second option is to set the correct `cornerRadius` by `overriding` the `layoutSubviews` method because this method ensures that your `cell` has laid out its size and you will get correct `frame` for `subViews`

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView!.frame.width / 2
        self.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, just to note, I did the second option

Comment: Yes, that is more cleaner as you are putting cell specific code in its own class.